# Looking for title of a short story about astronauts helmets being covered in moondust

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to recall a short story from around 40 or so years ago.
It involves two astronauts walking on the surface of the Moon and they are effectively blinded when their helmets become covered in moondust.

If I recall, they try to rub it off but some sort of static electrical effect makes them worse.
I have a horrible feeling it's a very well known Asimov or Clarke story but for the life of me I can't find it in any of my collection.

Any clues please? Thank you!

Comment: I am recaling another story Maybe by Clark or Asimov. About a hover craft like vessel carrying tourist, zipping around in the moon dust through the canyons of the moon. There is an accident (I think a bubble of gas popped below the vessel, and it got sucked down and buried beneath the dust. The novel was trying to rescue them before they ran out of Oxygen. I could have sworn they also had to deal with dust sticking to their face shields of their helmets. (The title was some thing like Moon Dust, or Dust Fall, or Moon Fall.)

Comment: @NJohnny, that's "A Fall Of Moondust" by Clarke. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fall_of_Moondust

Comment: @Pete Yep that was it. But reviewing the wiki link it does not appear they had a dust on the face shield problem. So I was probably mis-remembering that problem.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is ["Dust Rag"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55749) by Hal Clement; it's in Asimov's anthology *[Where Do We Go From Here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?282346)*, among other places.

This [review](http://variety-sf.blogspot.com/2009/02/hal-clement-dust-rag-short-story-lunar.html) mentions the static electricity and dust

> Life & death situation happens when they instinctively wipe their
> transparent space suit plastic in front of their eyes, as the vision
> begins getting unexpectedly blurred by haze. **Only, the wiping with
> space suit sleeve seems to stick the dust to surface in front of their
> eyes rather than remove it! They are quickly blinded.** And no hope of
> rescue: "there isn't enough fuel on the Moon to get a rescue tractor
> out here, even if anyone knew we were in trouble & could make the trip
> in time."

---

> But why cannot they wipe their faceplates? "Whenever two materials rub
> against each other, electrons come loose... Unless the materials are
> of identical electronic makeup, which for practical purposes means
> unless they are the same substance, one of them will hang onto the
> electrons a little - or a lot - better than the other, so one will
> have a negative net charge & the other a positive one. It's our
> misfortune that the difference between the plastic in our faceplates &
> that in the rest of the suits is the wrong way; when we rubbed the
> two, the faceplates picked up a charge opposite to that of the
> surrounding dust - probably negative, since I suppose the dust is
> positive & a transparent material should have a good grip on its
> electrons."

Comment: What can I do to improve this answer (I got a downvote for it)?

Comment: You got my +1, because it's the right answer.

Comment: And I thank you for it!  Recognized this one immediately, since I loved the Asimov anthology it's in (and I like Clement's works in general)

Comment: Yeah, I was coming here to post the same answer.

Comment: FYI: That physical effect has a name. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect